# Elasticsearch Rest client for Query DSL

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, spring-data-elasticsearch, elk, elasticsearch-rest-client

I am trying to write a method using ElasticsearchRestTemplate to fetch data from elasticsearch using query DSL ]. I looked into the documentation, but the documentation is not clear to me how to get the data from elasticsearch using java. Can anyone please help me how to fetch data from elasticsearch using Java client ( ElasticsearchRestTemplate ) by query DSL?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Elasticsearch does not support QueryDsl.